# How to resolve ActionMailer ignoring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Hi I'm making user register application by ruby on rails.
But ActionMailer process ignore my code.
When I try to use 
    UserMailer::confirmation_email.deliver
on rails s, I could send email.
But when I use bellow process, UserMailer::confirmation_email is ignored.
Do you know how to resolve it?

**user_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def create

    user = User.new(user_params)

    result = Users::RegisterService.register_user(user)
    render result
  end
end
```

**register_service.rb**

```
  module Users

    module RegisterService
      module_function
      def register_user(user = {})

        if user.save
          UserMailer::confirmation_email(user)
          result = { json: {status: 'User created successfully'}, status: :created }
        else
          result = { json: { errors: user.errors.full_messages }, status: :bad_request }
        end

        return result
      end
    end
  end
```

**user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'email@gmail.com'

  def confirmation_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url = 'http://192.16.8.33.10/user/confirm?confirmation_token=' +     @user.confirmation_token
    mail(
        to: @user.email,
        subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site',
        template_name: 'user_confirm'
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you have missed deliver `UserMailer::confirmation_email(user).deliver_now`

Comment: have you written `deliver` in your code? What do you mean your code got ignored?

Comment: Ah, it look like resolve. Thank you so match!  @PardeepDhingra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `deliver_now` to send email right away and `deliver_later` to send email asynchronously.

```
UserMailer::confirmation_email(user).deliver_now
```